# PHP Get Number From Text Input And Compare To Decimal From DB

Tags: php, mysql, variable-types

I'm running some PHP that queries regularly from a MySQL DB.

In my DB I have a decimal (5,4) field with an assortment of values, some of them real integers and some of them decimal numbers.

I'd like to take an `<input type="text">` tag from a form, `$_GET` the number the user entered, then compare it to a value in the DB.

Which of the three is the best way to go about this:

1. Convert the `$_GET['user_value]` variable to float, then compare to DB value.
2. Convert the `$_GET['user_value]` variable to integer, then compare to DB value.
3. Convert both `$_GET['user_value]` to strings, and then compare the two.

**BTW:** I need all the information after the decimal point.

**MY CODE - $user_answer is the user's input, $correct_answer is DB Value**

```
<?php
switch ($grid_type)
    {
        //If Single: Just Match Two Correct Answers
        case "single": 

            if($user_answer === $correct_answer)
            {
                $is_correct = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                $is_correct = 0;
            }

        break;

        //If Multiple: Check to see if user_answer Matches any of correct_answers
        case "multiple": 

            if($user_answer === $correct_answer OR $correct_answer_2 OR $correct_answer_3 OR $correct_answer_4 OR $correct_answer_5)
            {
                $is_correct = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                $is_correct = 0;
            }

        break;

        //If range: Check if user_answer is between the two range values
        case "range": 

            if($user_answer > $correct_range_bottom AND $user_answer < $correct_range_top)
            {
                $is_correct = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                $is_correct = 0;
            }

        break;

        default:
        "An Error Has Occured - All Of Your Base Are Belong To Us.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Numeric comparison, especially when you're expecting equality, is surprisingly difficult and application specific. (Is it money? Is it dimensions of building materials? Is it temperature?)  You haven't described your application. It's impossible to offer any advice except to say that it's pretty much always a fluke when two floating point numbers turn up precisely equal to one another.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - I see how it could look like I'm code-fishing. Added my actual code.

Comment: Converting from float to int means truncating, or rounding somehow, and I'm not sure that's what you want. If you don't mind losing information (the decimal part) then by all means convert it to int and compare. It's easier than comparing strings or floats.

Comment: Edited for clarification.

Comment: Ensure the value is numeric (PHP is_numeric) then use it in the 'where' clause of an sql 'prepared' query. The database engine and the driver will ensure it is in the correct format (decimal) for comparing with the database column values.

Comment: Yeah, but question is - will the DB engine round the number if there are too many digits after the decimal point.

Comment: Not sure how to respond to that comment. I assume that it uses the rules for decimal value types. I assume that 4 decimal places was chosen so that all values would evaluate correctly.

Comment: And yet, you responded perfectly. Thanks for your time man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tom None of the solution you listed are good.
What you want to do is this:

get whatever value the user entered (using POST/GET request - post is prefered) then

```
$user_value = $_POST['user_value'];
if(is_numeric(str_replace('.','',$user_value))){
$user_value = sprintf('%0.4f',$user_value);
echo $user_value;
}else{
echo 'Wrong number entered';
}
```

then you compare with the value from the DB.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Not sure I understand how a user can input a wrong number into the input field.

Comment: The input field is text. Meaning the user can enter anything. (eg: letters, numbers, underscore,special characters, all....)

Comment: Will do as soon as I get it tested, my friend. Patience's a virtue.